# Does the mode of MCMC samples equal the MAP of the posterior?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior, map-estimation

If I had millions of MCMC samples from a posterior, should the most frequent value among those samples (i.e., the peak of a histogram of those samples) at least in principle always equal the maximum-a-posteriori (MAP) estimate obtained through optimization?

In other words, are mode-of-samples and maximum-a-posteriori two ways to target the *same* quantity or could they be different under some circumstances (does it depend on properties of the sampling algorithm, for instance)?

Comment: Isn't the MAP known to be the mode of the posterior distribution?

Comment: Yes, that's what it's defined to be and therefore *intuitively* those two should coincide. I just wondered if there's a result proving (or disproving) this intuition.

Comment: Do you mean the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem, saying that empirical distributions converge to their true distributions? (Would MCMC count as $iid$ draws from that posterior distribution, though?)

Comment: Yes in principle. But Monte Carlo estimation of the mode is much more difficult than of other posterior quantities, such as mean, median or variance. There exist pathological cases, such as a "near point mass" of vary high density but with very little mass, which mean we can be off by a large amount in estimating the mode even in large samples. Are you asking because you are failing to get the correct mode in a simulation?

Comment: If you run a converging (ergodic) MCMC in a discrete space, the most frequent occurrence will converge to the MAP of the distribution. In a continuous space, assuming the (normalised or not) density value can be computed at each iteration of the MCMC run, the argument of the maximum density value will also (a.s.) converge to the MAP under continuity assumptions, if not as fast as with a converging simulated annealing algorithm (which is designed for this purpose).

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an that was pretty much the answer I was looking for.